# Troubleshoot continually reconnecting controllers?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have an XBox-360 and some wireless controllers. The TV is 15ft from the couch, and in a direct line of sight (eg, empty space between the two). But the controllers are continually disconnecting/reconnecting in every game I play.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be addressed on [an Xbox 360 Support page](http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/kb.aspx?ID=911111&lcid=1033&category=hardware), but that page is blocked where I work, so I can't check.

Having said that, if this is occurring with all your controllers, there may be some other nearby device that is interfering with the radio transmissions between the controllers and the console.

Answer (score 4):

First, check the batteries. If they are good, call Xbox Support, I had a similar problem and had to mail my Xbox to support to have them fix it. The problem was with the Xbox not the controllers.

Comment: If the green-light circle on the controllers flashes periodically, it's probably the batteries. Consider trying new batteries regardless to make sure.